# Average values in one file based upon values in another

Tags: matlab

I have a problem which I hope contributors can help me solve. I think it is best just to provide a working example:

I have two cells both of which consist of the same number of matrices (the result of reading a series of data files followed by some loop calculations). Each matrix is a column of decimal year days followed by a series of columns of data. Here is the dummy data:

```
A = [ 186.356 1 2 3 4;186.364 2 3 4 5;186.372 3 4 5 6]
B = [ 187.356 1 2 3 4;187.364 2 3 4 5;187.372 3 4 5 6]
C = [ 188.356 1 2 3 4;188.364 2 3 4 5;188.372 3 4 5 6]
x = {A,B,C}
D = [ 186.3568 1 2 3 4; 186.3576 2 3 4 5; 186.3584 3 4 5 6; 186.3592 4 5 6 7; 186.36 5 6 7 8; 186.3608 6 7 8 9; 186.3616 7 8 9 10; 186.3624 8 9 10 11; 186.3632 9 10 11 12; 186.364 10 11 12 13; 186.3648 11 12 13 14; 186.3656 12 13 14 15]
E = [ 187.3568 1 2 3 4; 187.3576 2 3 4 5; 187.3584 3 4 5 6; 187.3592 4 5 6 7; 187.36 5 6 7 8; 187.3608 6 7 8 9; 187.3616 7 8 9 10; 187.3624 8 9 10 11; 187.3632 9 10 11 12; 187.364 10 11 12 13; 187.3648 11 12 13 14; 187.3656 12 13 14 15]
F = [ 188.3568 1 2 3 4; 188.3576 2 3 4 5; 188.3584 3 4 5 6; 188.3592 4 5 6 7; 188.36 5 6 7 8; 188.3608 6 7 8 9; 188.3616 7 8 9 10; 188.3624 8 9 10 11; 188.3632 9 10 11 12; 188.364 10 11 12 13; 188.3648 11 12 13 14; 188.3656 12 13 14 15]
y = {D,E,F}
```

My intention is to sum the data columns contained within both x and y. However you can see that the resolution of the data in y is much higher than x therefore I would first like to average the data in y based upon the timesteps of x.

As an example the first time period which matches between x and y correspond to row 1 in matrix A but only the first 10 rows in matrix D. The sum of the first row in A is 10:

```
sumA = sum(A(1,2:end),2)
```

and the average of the first 10 rows in D is

```
sumD = sum(mean(D(1:10,2:end)),2)
```

resulting in a total of 38.

This is a simple example; I have many rows of data in two large cells. I suspect I need to extract the data from the cells, loop through the data whilst rewriting to another cell of the same dimensions as the first two cells, x and y but am at a loss as to where to start. Any help would be great.

## Edit

In looking to clarify my problem I realise I made a mistake in the original question. This is no doubt the cause of the confusion.

Everything above is correct however the sum of the first 10 rows of D:

```
sumD = sum(mean(D(1:10,2:end)),2)
sumD =

28
```

should actually be added to the sum of the second row in A:

```
sumA = sum(A(2,2:end),2)
sumA =

14
```

This is because all the values in rows 1-10 of column 1 in matrix D are larger than the the value in row 1 and column 1 of matrix A but smaller than or equal to row 2 and column 2 of matrix A. It might be easier if increase the dummy data in matrix D:

```
D = [ 186.3568 1 2 3 4; 186.3576 2 3 4 5; 186.3584 3 4 5 6; 186.3592 4 5 6 7; 186.36 5 6 7 8; 186.3608 6 7 8 9; 186.3616 7 8 9 10; 186.3624 8 9 10 11; 186.3632 9 10 11 12; 186.364 10 11 12 13; 186.3648 11 12 13 14; 186.3656 12 13 14 15; 186.3664 13 14 15 16; 186.3672 14 15 16 17; 186.368 15 16 17 18; 186.3688 16 17 18 19; 186.3696 17 18 19 20; 186.3704 18 19 20 21; 186.3712 19 20 21 22; 186.372 20 21 22 23]
```

Now the result would be a two value vector. The first value would be 28+14, the result of the sum of the second row in A (or sumA) and the sum of the mean of the first 10 rows of data in matrix D (or sumD). The second value would the sum of the third row in A, lets say sumA2:

```
sumA2 = sum(A(3,2:end),2)
sumA2 =

18
```

and sumD2:

```
sumD2 = sum(mean(D(11:end,2:end)),2)
sumD2 =

68
sumA2+sumD2

ans =

86
```

I would like this process to be automated so that I can go through each matrix in the cell. i.e. if I start with cells x and y with dims:

```
x = 

[300x5 double]    [300x5 double]    [300x5 double]
y = 

[2000x5 double]    [2000x5 double]    [2000x5 double]
```

I would like the result to be

```
z = 

[300x1 double]    [300x1 double]    [300x1 double]
```

I am not sure if that makes things any clearer but lets see!

Comment: Very well written question, but it needs a bit of clarification: how did you correlate the first row of `A` to the first 10 rows of `D`? Are you considering some level of tolerance? If so, what?

Comment: Hi Roney, to clarify: The first 10 rows of D are chosen based upon the fact that the value in the first column (the decimal day of the year) lie in the range between the first and second values in the first column of D (the equivalent decimal day of this dataset). I hope that now makes more sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you use the values to illustrate? Also, it'd be better if you edit it into the question instead of commenting it.

Comment: Do you really want to *average* the data in `Y`? Feels like *interpolating* is the way to go...What I mean is, interpolate all teh data in `Y` to meet timestamps in `X`, and sum. If you are only dealing with a difference in resolution, then interpolation would be the way to go. If there is a significant amount of noise in `Y` that is abscent in `X`, then I agree that averaging is better. So, which will it be? :)

Comment: Hi Rody, there is indeed a significant amount of noise in in the data with higher resolution hence my thinking to average; this is my preferred method. For every one value of x I have 110 values of y...

Comment: Why are `x` and `y` cells? They both contain matrices of the same sizes, why aren't they just a 3d arrays?

Comment: do the times in `y` always fall between the times in `x`? If not, then some data will be truncated by your specification. For example, if you added two more rows onto D, say `[189 16 17 18 19; 190 20 21 22 23]`, how would you want these rows to map into the reduced data set?

Comment: If you use a centered mean, then you don't have to worry about accidentally truncating your data if some values lie outside. For example, let T be the time vector from x. For time `T(i)`, you currently average data with times `T(i-1) < t <= T(i)`. If your hi-res time data has one or more data points with time greater than `T(n)`, then you lose those values. If you do a centered-mean, you average data with times `T(i-1) < t <= T(i+1)` instead, which guarantees that you don't truncate any data, while keeping your averaging consistent.

Comment: Why don't you comment/accept/upvote/reward my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I managed to properly get all your tricky specifications, here is the code:

```
function z = foo(x, y)
  z = x;
  for i = 1:length(x)
    z{i} = sum(z{i}(:, 2:end), 2);  
    dmin = 0;
    for j = 1:size(x{i}, 1)
      dmax = x{i}(j, 1);
      t = y{i}(:, 1);
      mask = t > dmin & t <= dmax;
      if any(mask)
        z{i}(j) = z{i}(j) + sum(median(y{i}(mask, 2:end)), 2);
      end
      dmin = dmax;
    end
  end
end
```

For the given `x` and `y` from the question, for the answer `z` I have `z{1} == z{2} == z{3}`, and

```
>> z{1}
ans =
10
42
70
```

If I substitute `D` from your "Edit" section, I get `z{1}(3) == 86`, as you claimed.

Nothing special about the code. `dmin` and `dmax` hold current dates range based on the value of the first column of a matrix from `x` (i.e. `A`, `B`, etc.). An `if any(mask)` statement is needed to avoid taking median from empty array, which leads to a vector of `NaN`'s, which screws up the sum.